# Существует ли более лаконичный способ проверки параметра?

Tags: c#, проектирование

В функции BubbleSort я использую sortOrder, после чего проверяю его через switch-case.
Если sortOrder = SortOrder.Asc, то по возрастанию, если *.Desc - по убыванию.
Существует ли более элегантный способ проверять переменную switch-case?

```
public enum SortOrder
    {
        Asc,
        Desc
    }
    public static class Sorting
    {
        public static void BubbleSort<T>(this T[] array, SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.ASC) where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 1; j < array.Length - i; j++)
                {
                    
                    if (array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j]) > 0)
                        Swap(ref array[j - 1], ref array[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Дело в том, что я хочу сделать ещё и быструю сортировку, в которой будет использоваться рекурсия и постоянно сравнивать sortOrder - не круто.
Может использовать явные функции - BubbleSortAsc, но, как по мне, это выглядит не очень красиво, да и код будет множиться (проблему с повторяющимся кодом в switch-case не решит).

Как мне лучше поступить?
Спасибо.

Comment: Передавайте компаратор и убирайте switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно немного считерить.

```
public enum SortOrder
{
    Asc = 1,
    Desc = -1
}
```

```
if (Math.Sign(array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j])) == (int)sortOrder)
    Swap(ref array[j - 1], ref array[j]);
```

Свич уберется, сравнение будет работать быстро.

Comment: Но тогда не совсем ясно, что писать в `{ ... }`, так как условие может соответствовать сразу двум случаям::
`[j-1] > [j] и sortOrder.Asc`
`[j-1] < [j] и sortOrder.Desc`

Comment: @Danila не будет, писать тоже самое. Вы проверьте сначала, я вам показал только места, где внести изменения. Свич не надо, просто как метод был только для одного варианта. Дополнил код.

Comment: Умно, умно, спасибо!

Comment: Другой вариант: `if (array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j]) * (int)SortOrder > 0)`

Comment: @pasx тоже вариант.

Comment: @pasx в этом варианте есть маленький баг `int.MinValue * -1`, если конечно `CompareTo` способно такое вернуть.

Comment: @aepot Вы правы, `CompareTo` часто выводить только -1, 0 или 1. Но в документации написано, меньше 0, 0 или более 0. А с `int.MinValue * -1` будет баг:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622347/1-int-minvalue-int-minvalue-is-this-a-bug